# Is there any bulkUpdate (similar to bulkDelete_!!) in Mapper?

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

Is there a bulkUpdate method similar to bulkDelete_!! in mapper so that i can update records in underlying table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my knowledge , Unfortunately in order to perform bulk update ( based on some criteria ) we have to use sql query only. No method similar to bulkDelete_!! available for bulk Update.

For example:

```
def updateNameById (newName : String,  id : Long) = {  
    val updateString = "update MyModel set name = ? where id = ?"    
    DB.use(DefaultConnectionIdentifier) { conn =>
        DB.prepareStatement(updateString, conn) { stmt =>
              stmt.setString(1, newName)
              stmt.setLong(2, id)
              stmt.executeUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no bulkUpdate in Mapper, you would have to do a findAll, edit the records and then do a .save on them.

Comment: but that will be querying the database twice, won't it ? ( Once for findAll and onceagain for save )

Comment: That is correct.  To avoid that you would have to use a custom sql, like @vkantiya wrote